# Insert multiple paragraphs and images inside a circle using Java iText

Tags: java, itext

i want to generate a pdf label for CD using java itext. i have drawn the circle but i am unable to set image and multiple paragraphs inside the circle.
Below is the code snippet.[code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhAnJ.png)

```
 String printingPath = "CD_label.pdf"; 
      Document document = new Document(new Rectangle(PageSize.A4));
      PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document,new FileOutputStream(printingPath));
      document.open();

      PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent(); 
      cb.setRGBColorFill(0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);
      BaseColor colorval = new BaseColor(102,178,255);
      cb.setColorStroke(colorval); 
      cb.circle(300.0f, 650.0f, 150.0f);
      cb.circle(300.0f, 650.0f, 20.0f); 
      cb.stroke();


      //cb.setFontAndSize(BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA,BaseFont.CP1257,BaseFont.EMBEDDED), 10); 
      //cb.beginText(); 
      //cb.resetRGBColorStroke();
      //cb.setTextMatrix(320, 420); 
      //cb.showText("Text inside cd");

     // ColumnText.showTextAligned(cb, Element.ALIGN_LEFT,new Phrase("Hello itext"),50, 700, 0); cb.endText();

      Image img = Image.getInstance("Symbol.png");
      img.setAbsolutePosition(270f, 740f); 
      img.scaleAbsolute(60, 34);

      document.close();
```

Comment: Could you show your attempt with circle?

Comment: i have added the code snippet for drawing circle

Comment: i have also attached the screenshot of the attempt to insert paragraph into it

Comment: Fine. Post that attempt as text - if that code could be fixed it would be easier for others to copy it than rewrite from screenshot (you can read more here: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Do you get any error or it has just no effect?

Comment: i have pasted the code snippet. There is now effect of text. text is not displayed inside circle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Why don't you see your text?

You set the fill color to WHITE:

```
cb.setRGBColorFill(0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);
```

Text (usually) is drawn by *filling* glyph outlines defined in some font. Thus, your uncommented text drawing code

```
cb.setFontAndSize(BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA,BaseFont.CP1257,BaseFont.EMBEDDED), 10); 
cb.beginText(); 
cb.resetRGBColorStroke();
cb.setTextMatrix(320, 420); 
cb.showText("Text inside cd");

ColumnText.showTextAligned(cb, Element.ALIGN_LEFT,new Phrase("Hello itext"),50, 700, 0);
cb.endText();
```

**does** draw text... in WHITE on WHITE...

If you remove that `cb.setRGBColorFill` instruction (or select a clearly different fill color), you'll see your text:

[image: screen shot]

*(The point (320, 420) clearly is outside a circle with center (300, 650) and radius 150, consequentially so is your "Text inside cd" text...)*

Another issue: `ColumnText.showTextAligned` starts its own text object, so to create a valid PDF you must move it after your `cb.endText()`:

```
cb.setFontAndSize(BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA,BaseFont.CP1257,BaseFont.EMBEDDED), 10); 
cb.beginText(); 
cb.resetRGBColorStroke();
cb.setTextMatrix(320, 420); 
cb.showText("Text inside cd");
cb.endText();

ColumnText.showTextAligned(cb, Element.ALIGN_LEFT,new Phrase("Hello itext"),50, 700, 0);
```

#### Why don't you see your image?

Because you don't add it!

If you add it to your `PdfContentByte cb`

```
    Image img = Image.getInstance("Symbol.png");
    img.setAbsolutePosition(270f, 740f); 
    img.scaleAbsolute(60, 34);
    cb.addImage(img);
```

the result becomes like this:

[image: screen shot]

*(I obviously don't have your image, so I use a simple example image instead.)*